What was the first mobile game on a portable device?
Mobile games are incredibly common. If you have a phone, chances are you have or had at least one mobile game installed on your phone.
What was the first mobile game?
For this question, a mobile game is any game that can be played on a small handheld device (including but not limited to modern smartphones). Games played on hand-held game consoles (such as the Gameboy or 3DS) count. If external controllers or being plugged into a display device are required, it is disqualified. The answer has to include both the game and the device it is played on.

I'd be interested to know the downvote reason.

Not the one who downvoted, but I'm curious if the Osborne 1 qualifies, seeing as it has its own display and controller (in the form of a keyboard).

@Nolonar Games played on that would count, but just the console wouldn't (the answer has to be a game on a platform).

@Nolonar it's beat for first game anyway. Ball Toss Up game and watch is April 1980, though on dedicated hardware.

And it's going to be past the 4004 which introduced VLSI in 1971, so there's the decade.

There's also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(console) which is a questionable entry.

Is Mattel's Auto Race a valid answer?

The separation of game and console makes this a bit tricky - I'd totally see something like Auto Race as a handheld game.
If we are talking mobile phones only it's Tetris on the Hagenuk MT-2000 in 1994.

@pinckerman Yes, that works.

what's a game? I don't read anything in the question that disqualifies games that have a physical respresentation of the state.  peg solataire,  15 puzzle,  a deck of cards?

@Jasen This is a site for video games, as noted in the Tour. Board games are off-topic somewhat by default.

Thinked about mastermind but electronic portable version is 1977. There was something with questions and answers and cables. When cable put in correct hole then bulb light. Do not remember name and year but was something like 1920-1940. Was smal box with battery and cards  to put in and cable connected to box. Anyone?

@k_z we had a boardgame like that here in Italy, there were sheets with holes and you had to connect them using cables which led to an acoustic feedback, but that was from 1967

Does the game need to be software stored on memory of some kind and run on the separate hardware of the handheld device, or is hardware-only in scope, hand-held devices where there is no software, just hardware?

While the Wikipedia article "Mobile game" states that "the term [mobile game] also refers to all games that are played on any portable device", I wouldn't say this is common usage. Could the title be changed to "first game on a portable device"?

Downvote Reason: Your question are iterative and show no research effort. This site is about helping people who have "searched and researched" before posting see this help center article, i.e. put in a significant effort themselves before asking a question. Asking multiple "What was the first..."-Questions seems less like someone actually looking for answers to a topic they couldn't research themselves and more like someone seeding questions, farming for upvotes or just throwing interesting ideas onto the site, to engage with the community.

... Please note that I use the word 'seem' here, as I have no way of discerning your actual intentions or reasons and do not mean to judge you. In the case of this questions, a simple sentence such as the following, should have been an absolute minimum "From what I could find online X was the first Handheld Console and Y was the first game on it, is there anything that came before that, that could also qualify"?

@TreeSpawned Ok, thanks for the in-depth feedback.

This is my guess, Mattel's Auto Race released in 1976:

The player controls a car on a three-lane track and moves between them with a switch. Opponent vehicles move toward the player, in an effect similar to vertical scrolling, and the player must avoid them. A second control shifts gears from 1-4, with the speed increasing for each.
The cars are represented by red LEDs on a playfield which covers only a small portion of the case. The audio consists of beeps.



Interestingly that Wikipedia article says it is the first handheld electronic game to use only solid-state electronics which implies there may have been earlier handhelds without solid state electronics ....

Waco's 1972 Electro Tic Tac Toe is an earlier handheld, although it's mostly mechanical. Going back earlier than this you get into purely mechanical games with no electrical components at all, which technically OP didn't disallow, but the answer to that is likely prehistoric.

@James_pic This is a stack for video games, so it’s implied OP didn’t mean purely mechanical games.

@James_pic: There's a video on YouTube with a teardown of one these ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWrp2MKiyJg scroll to about 7:30 for the tl;dw) and I think it can't count as a video game since it is really only a set of switchable lights.

@Darren Of course, that begs the question as to what counts as a "video game". Does it require a screen display capable of rendering some form of rasterized graphics? That would likely disqualify this answer as well (unless this counts as an extremely primitive "LED screen"), but would that also mean that the first "video games" made on vector displays don't count? Also, OP stipulated "hand-held console", which to me would imply a hand-held gaming device capable of playing multiple games, which would also disqualify this answer.

@Abion47 if you want a device capable of playing multiple games then the first hand-held gaming console probably was 1978 Merlin, but it didn't have a LED screen

@pinckerman, I had that thing! I also remember that at some point I had a scientific calculator that included a “racing game”. It had a red 7-segment LED display. The game used only the three horizontal segments. The player car was fixed and could be moved up and down, the other cars moved relative to it. The player car was illuminated a bit more brightly. There were keys for acceleration and brakes. There was the “car” sound that reflected the speed and there was a collision sound.
